# Bundle multiple java application

Tags: java, bundle

I want to know if there is a way to bundle multiple java applications as a a single war file. This requirement is more due to budget reason . Any suggestion on how to achieve this will be very helpful.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: A web app (war) file is a single web app. You can play games with routing *inside* that app, but it's a single app. If you're using an app server, you might be able to do something with EAR files, I don't recall.

Comment: @JFPicard I don't see this as a request for anything other than what are the restrictions of war files.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put multiple web applications into a single WAR file.  A WAR defines a single webapp.

There are a couple of alternatives:

- As suggested by Dave Newton, construct a single webapp that combines the functionality of your multiple webapps; e.g. as different parts of their URL namespace.
- Distribute multiple WAR files as a single ZIP file, and provide instructions for unzipping and then deploying the WARs one at a time.
- The same as the previous, but use an EAR file instead of an *ad hoc* ZIP file.  If you have web container that supports deployment of EAR files, you don't need to deploy manually.  (But Tomcat doesn't, for example.)

Answer (score 0):

Using build tools like maven/gradle it is possible to produce 1 war/jar from several projects.

It is straightforward if other Java apps are just jar files, but if there are all web apps, you would need to think how to resolve conflicts.
For example all web resources like html, css must be in different folders.
framework configuration like web.xml must be cleverly combined,
it may be easier to define one new big, than implement logic of how to merge them.

All this complication are actually why industry is moving in opposite direction, i.e. producing more and smaller apps instead of integrating into one, as every piece is becoming independent.

---

If you want specific answer, you need to give exact info about what framework you are using, what is typical file structure, what is web server in use.